# Automation of Data discovery and classification in Azure SQL databases using ARM template

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to automate data discovery and classification in Azure SQL databases using ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

Data Discovery & Classification cannot be configured at the database level and cannot be part of an ARM database template. Data Discovery & Classification can be configured at the server level when you enable "Advanced Data Security" and you configure a storage account for the Vulnerability Assessment.

"Advanced Data Security" contains Data Discovery & Classification, Vulnerability Assessment, and Advanced Threat Protection.

Advanced Data Security is paid for logical server not by the number of databases. That explains why it is not configured at the database level and cannot be part of an ARM database template.